# Compose preview rendering is slow in migration project

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

I am currently working on a project where we need to implement composables.
Due to the build tasks it's taking more time (~ 1m to 2m) to render even a simple text color change.
So, decided to exclude the gradle tasks while previewing the compose.
Is it possible? . If so, can provide some gradle task inputs?

Answer (score 0):

For one you're never going to get speeds that rival XML preview times because they were less complex.

Also I don't know what build of AS you're using but Hedeghog and Iguana seemed to have boost build times as well.

In addition I found that this addition helped shave seconds of as well

Help -> Edit Custom VM options...
Set the following flag: -Ddesign.tools.project.system.class.loader.cache.max.size=50000000
Restart studio

Also when creating Previews you want them to be very simple;
Use Mock-Data; Dont use viewModels, try to create small Composables and preview those instead of just creating a large screen and creating the UI within that one screen

Comment: Reducing build time will impact the preview rendering time. Do we have any official statement that it will do reduce or not ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @KarthikeyanVe If you want to reduce build time, you can modularize your app, use KSP and other things; But if you're just previewing a small component, it shouldn't take 1 to 2 minutes to update a preview. Make sure you have live edit enabled and keep your Previews small like I said